# AngularJS: ng-options' values are undefined, they are in label

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I've been learning AngularJS, but now I'm in a situation where 
`ng-options`' values are undefined, and those values are displayed in label.

I've been googling for hours but I don't see a specific explanation when such a thing can happen.

To clarify the situation, here is a simplified code.

```
<select ng-model="objA[{{$temp}}]" ng-options="i for i in objB[{{$temp}}] track by $index">
</select>
//{{$temp}} is an PHP variable and I'm using laravel. It holds 1.
```

In Javascript,

```
$scope.objA = {1:2};
$scope.objB = {1:[0,1,2]};
```

I expected that there would be three options and the values are `0,1,2`, respectively.
However, the results were...

```
<option value="undefined" label="0">0</option>
<option value="undefined" label="1">1</option>
<option value="undefined" label="2">3</option>
```

Any advice will be appreciated!

**I forgot to mention one thing... I'm using laravel, so `$temp` has to be in curly brackets.**

Answer (score 2):

The problem that I see is with the ng-model.
From AngularJS website:

> ## `select as`
>
> Using `select as` will bind the result of the `select`
>   expression to the model, but the value of the `<select>` and `<option>`
>   html elements will be either the index (for array data sources) or
>   property name (for object data sources) of the value within the
>   collection. If a `track by` expression is used, the result of that
>   expression will be set as the value of the `option` and `select` elements.

Your `objA` can be array or object.
If array then you have to use like: `label for value in objA`
If object then you have to use like: `label for (key , value) in objA`

See below for the example:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('HomeController', function($scope) {

    $scope.objA = {
      1: {
        1: 1,
        2: 2,
        3: 3
      }
    };

    $scope.objB = {
      1: [1, 2, 3]
    };
    $scope.selected = 1;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="HomeController">
  <label>With Object</label>
  <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="key for (key, val) in objA[1]">
</select>

  <label>With Array</label>
  <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="item for item in objB[1]">
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I simply removed the `track by` and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.objB` is **not** an array: it is an objet that **contains** an array.

You should change it to `$scope.objB = [0, 1, 2]` or change your code to

```
ng-options="i for i in objB.propName[{{$temp}}] track by $index">
```

Answer (score 0):

`{{ }}` are the same for Laravel and Angular.

[Read this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/quick-tip-using-laravel-blade-with-angularjs) to learn how to avoid this (Meh).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

**Observation :** Just use `temp` instead of `{{temp}}`

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.temp = 1;
    $scope.objA = {1:2};
    $scope.objB = {1:[0,1,2]};
    $scope.selectedOption = function(item) {
      console.log(item);
    }
});

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-model="objA[temp]" ng-options="i for i in objB[temp]" ng-change="selectedOption(objA[temp])">
</select>
</div>
```